# A Program that accepts looping limit and will serve as multiplier of itself(per column) using C++

Tags: c++

I have a Activity that accepts looping limit and will serve as multiplier of itself(per column) this is the example output

```
3   9   27
9  27   81
27 81  243
```

but this is my output

```
Enter number of rows: 3
3 9 27 
81 243 729 
2187 6561 19683
```

This is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int rows;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
 
    int i, j;
    int num = 1;
    int plc = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1 ; j<=rows ; j++)
        {
            
            plc = plc * rows;
           cout << plc << " ";
        }
        
      
        
        cout << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Where I did wrong?

Comment: You're continuing the next row with the last result of the previous row. The first element is 3, 3*3, 3*3*3. (You're going to need another variable. Was that what you intend to use `num` for?)

Answer (score 0):

You are only multiplying the previous value by rows(3) each time and not taking into account the row and columns, the code below will solve your problem:

```
int main()
{

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    int i, j;
    int num = 1;
    int plc = 1;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++)
        {
            plc = 1;

            for (int mult=0;mult< ((i - 1) + j);mult++)
            {
                plc *= 3;
            }

            cout << plc << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Gives the expected outout:

```
3   9   27
9  27   81
27 81  243
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to use the `num` variable?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int rows = ::atoi(argv[1]);
    int num = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {        
        int plc = num;
        num *= rows;
        for(int j = 1 ; j<=rows ; j++)
        {            
            plc = plc * rows;
            std::cout << plc << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
Program stdout
3 9 27 
9 27 81 
27 81 243
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/sfn119vTs